# Why animation was used in several scenes of Revolver?

Tags: film-techniques, revolver

[Revolver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revolver_%282005_film%29). Though, An amazing movie regarding EGO, EGO and EGO...

At most times, the movie included actual animations of Andre, Liotta and several other characters. Like - when the money was stolen, Macha, Lord John, all were in cartoons. Why was such a theme introduced at that time?

Was that simply to cover the actual guns and blood used by the fellas? If not, why then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although many viewers felt like it was ripping off (or homaging?) the origin of O-Ren Ishii seen in *Kill Bill Vol.1* (released two years earlier), other critics have alluded to the notion that the animation technique was used to illustrate a specific moment of 'non-reality'.

Indeed, a comment made on the [Film Geek Show blog](http://filmgeeksshow.blogspot.ca/2008/04/spoiler-alert-revolver.html) suggests:

*This was to give you hints that what Jake was seeing were not only **not** real but also what elements of Jake's subconsciousness they were.*

I would also add that the type of animation used - the rotoscoped variety favored by Richard Linklater in *A Scanner Darkly* which was all about augmented reality - served as an indicator to the viewer that this was unreal or dreamed.

Answer (score 3):

From an [**interview**](http://web.archive.org/web/20071206185445/http://www.iesb.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=3823&Itemid=99) **with director Guy Ritchie:**

> **There's a lot of stylistic choices in Revolver, such as the animated scene. What's the idea behind them?**
>
> - *It's funny, because I wrote it before 'Kill Bill' came out so I really wanted to have a whole animated sequence in the thing and fucking 'Kill Bill' came out and people went "oh, he's just copying Tarantino.*
>
>   *So I always wanted to integrate somehow, an animated sequence. I was always interested in 3-D/2-D. So it's the old 2-D fashion, but in 3-D. In fact, I wanted to make a movie like it so it got in there.*
>
>   *Actually, it was about - well, **there's the simple version and there's the complicated version** - let's stick with the simple one. **The simple one is that I just wanted to use animation in the movie.***
>
> **But you think that it ties into the film's theme?**
>
> - *Well it does. That's the complicated version. **The complicated version is about, sort of dual universes, parallel universes and whatnot.***